# Where is the installed packages database in a Debian system?

Tags: debian, deb

If I run dpkg -l on a Debian-like system I will get a full list of installed packages.

But where can I find this database in the system? Can I get the same result by just reading a plain-text file on the system?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

as determined by running the following zsh commandline:

`strace dpkg -l|&grep open`

as well as

`strace dpkg --get-selections|&grep open`